# Adding Vuforia Plugin on Unity Editor with an M1 chip does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, apple-m1, unity-editor

I tried to install the Vuforia plugin on Unity Editor but it did not work.

The error message came out like this:

```
Plugins: Couldn't open /Users/jorisdejong/TestM1/Library/PackageCache/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@efa13d4486/Vuforia/Plugins/OSXUniversal/FileDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FileDriver, error: dlopen(/Users/usename/TestM1/Library/PackageCache/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@efa13d4486/Vuforia/Plugins/OSXUniversal/FileDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FileDriver, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:/Users/username/TestM1/Library/PackageCache/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@efa13d4486/Vuforia/Plugins/OSXUniversal/FileDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FileDriver: mach-o, but wrong architecture /Users/username/TestM1/Library/PackageCache/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@efa13d4486/Vuforia/Plugins/OSXUniversal/FileDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FileDriver: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I then asked the Vuforia forum on [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/vuforia-engine-mac-m1#comment-74281).

It was recommended to use an Intel emulator to run Unity Editor.

Answer (score 0):

I then installed Rosetta 2.

I then looked at the current Unity Editor info and it confirmed that I had downloaded the Apple version.

I went back to the [Unity download archives](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) and downloaded the Intel Unity Editor. It automatically replaced the Apple version once installed.

I can now add Vuforia plugin into the Unity Editor.